# Database query in SQL Server with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wanted to check if there was an easier way or better way to write the below query? I have to union join around 10 tables `MMA_AUDITSUM_STG` in the below I have only done two. Is there away to get around typing all the columns name one by one and include the join from `MMA_SITE_MST`? I'm using SQL Server to store the data.

```
SELECT 
    a.CLIENT_NAME AS [BRAND], a.SITE_NO AS [SITE NO],
    a.SITE_NAME AS [SITE],
    c.FILTER_1 AS [AREA], c.FILTER_2 AS [REGION],
    a.MANAGER,
    a.AUDIT_DATE AS [db.audit_date], a.THIS_AUDIT_SCORE AS [SCORE],
    a.ALERTS_FLAG AS [ALERTS], a.REPEAT_FLAG AS [REPEAT ISSUES],
    a.ACTION_PLAN_FLAG AS [ACTION PLAN FAILURE],
    a.Cash, a.Revenue, a.Stock, 
    a.[Unaccounted Stock], a.[People & Payroll], 
    a.[Safe], a.[Security], a.[Petty Cash], a.[Tills],
    a.[Bankings], a.[Sales], a.[Vouchers & Discounting],
    a.[PDQ], a.[Administration], 
    a.[Stock Verification], a.[Stock Management], a.[Ordering]
FROM 
    MMA_AUDITSUM_STG_34 As a
INNER JOIN 
    MMA_SITE_MST AS c ON a.CLIENT_ID = c.CLIENT_ID
                      AND a.SITE_ID= c.SITE_ID
                      AND a.SITE_NAME= c.SITE_NAME

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    b.CLIENT_NAME, b.SITE_NO, b.SITE_NAME,
    c.FILTER_1, c.FILTER_2,
    b.MANAGER, b.AUDIT_DATE, b.THIS_AUDIT_SCORE,
    b.ALERTS_FLAG, b.REPEAT_FLAG, b.ACTION_PLAN_FLAG,
    b.Cash, b.Revenue, b.Stock, b.[Unaccounted Stock],
    b.[People & Payroll], b.[Safe], b.[Security],
    b.[Petty Cash], b.[Tills], b.[Bankings], b.[Sales],
    b.[Vouchers & Discounting], b.[PDQ], b.[Administration],
    b.[Stock Verification], b.[Stock Management], b.[Ordering]
FROM 
    MMA_AUDITSUM_STG_35 As b
INNER JOIN 
    MMA_SITE_MST As c ON b.CLIENT_ID = b.CLIENT_ID
                      AND b.SITE_ID = c.SITE_ID
                      AND b.SITE_NAME = c.SITE_NAME
```

Any views welcome as I'm still learning so not sure if I'm doing the above right even though it gets me the result I need :)

Thank you in advance

John

Comment: Your query is fine.  I might question the data model that puts similar data in different tables, rather than into a single table.

Comment: You can simplify your question by joining the `MMA_SITE_MST` to the result of the `union all` of all the `MMA_AUDITSUM_STG_%` tables, but I agree with Gordon - the real question is why use different tables for similar data?

Comment: Thanks for replies, data model is due to a client having multiple brands however my data model doesn't have brands so hat to set them up as different clients. This allows me to create dashboards which combines all or can filtered by brand. I agree and the remainder of my clients i don't have to join. Thanks for confirm I'm doing it right :)

Comment: One way to void typing is the use the same alias.  Why a then b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF indeed all separate tables are required, you might think about creating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_MMA_AuditSum(
  SELECT * FROM MMA_AUDITSUM_STG_34
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM MMA_AUDITSUM_STG_35
  UNION ALL
  ....
)
```

And afterwards join it to your MMA_SITE_MST

```
SELECT a.CLIENT_NAME
     ,a.SITE_NO
     ,a.SITE_NAME
     ,a.FILTER_1
     ,a.FILTER_2
     ,b.*
  FROM MMA_SITE_MST AS a
  JOIN cte AS b ON a.CLIENT_ID= b.CLIENT_ID
                AND a.SITE_ID= b.SITE_ID
                AND a.SITE_NAME= b.SITE_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know you could do this. Would it be better based on replies I have received to create a stored procedure which moves the data into one table? In a sense it would be the same as your create view but not temporary.

Comment: Nope, it is not the same: a procedure which copies the data produces - as described - more data. depending on the amount of data in your table this might be a huge amount, since you will have twice as many records in your DB: once in the original Position, once in your new table. Creating a view is not temporary! Additionally, the data will not be duplicated but queries will be Kind of redirected to the original records. In other words: the original records Change and you see the Change in the view as well.

Comment: You could look into an Indexed View too. This will keep the data up to date and you will not need to run the stored proc every time you add data for it to be up to date.

Comment: Ok, I tried the view but could not get past the first part create view? Seems to have an error near first SELECT and the last bracket ). Will keep trying mind otherwise i will continue what I was doing. Thanks for the tips all:)

Comment: Mea culpa :-/

Should be "CREATE VIEW v_MMA_AuditSum AS(" Instead of "CREATE VIEW v_MMA_AuditSum("

Comment: I decided to combine the data into one table. Which I created a stored procedure to update / move the data over. The number of rows is small hundreds. Thanks any way I will look into the view idea later.